# Livevalidation setting youtube url validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, youtube, validation

I am using [livevalidation](http://livevalidation.com/examples) to validate a form input field where it asks for a youtube video url and I am trying to create a url rule so that it validates when the user inputs
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11chars. I tried to combine the partialmatch option in the link above like so:

```
var link = new LiveValidation('link');
link.add( Validate.Inclusion, { within: [ 'http://' , 'www', 'youtube.com/watch?v=' ], partialMatch: true } )
```

and combine it with this length example:

```
var link = new LiveValidation('link');
link.add( Validate.Length, { minimum: 50, maximum: 50 } );
```

but obviously this looks clumsy and I dont think it'll be very effective if it worked properly.

Is there a possible way to combine some of the examples from the link above to validate the youtube url properly? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Validate.Format` with a regular expression:

```
 link.add(Validate.Format, { pattern: /^http\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[a-z0-9]{11}$/i });
```

**Edit:** To validate links with additional query parameters, you can use something like this:

```
/^http\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[a-z0-9]{11}(&.*)?$/i
```

Comment: @usr122212 - Try it and let us know.  :-)  It's from the page you linked to: http://livevalidation.com/examples#exampleFormat

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @gilly3 but it fails validation with the youtube links.

Comment: @usr122212 - I had a one character typo in my RegExp that made it only allow lowercase letters.  I've edited my answer with the fix.

Comment: @gilly3 thanks alot this works great, I had one more question, some youtube urls are like this: .http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11chars&feature=feedu. would it be possible to accept urls that has & sign after the 11chars with any examples shown in the livevalidation page?

Comment: @usr122212 - I added a regex to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
link.add(Validate.Format, { pattern: /^http\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[a-zA-Z0-9---_]{11}$/ });
```

this works! didnt know I could just use regex to do it so I tweaked @gilly3 code a bit

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that validates for both your JavaScript & PHP, and does it for three kinds of URLs: the classic (?v=), the AJAXed one (#!v=) and the short version (youtu.be). It also supports international URLs.

```
/http:\/\/(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:[a-z]{2,3}\.)?youtube\.com\/watch(?:\?|#\!)v=)([\w-]{11}).*/gi
```

Code snippet found on Snipplr :)